# get available height of browser window from within iframes

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have the following structure of my website:

```
<html>
  <iframe>
    <iframe>
    </iframe>
  </iframe>
<html>
```

I am prgramming the part of the most inner `iframe`. Now I want to determine the available `height` of the browser window (starting under the `menubar` and ending before possible `toolbar`s).

I have **IE9** and tried somthing like:

```
window.innerHeight
```

**(result undefined) and**

```
window.parent.document.body.clientHeight
```

**(not the height I expected)**.

How do I get the `height`? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> window.parent.document.body.clientHeight
>
> (not the height I expected). How do I get the height? Thanx in
>   advance.

That is because `window.parent` would be the iframe above it, not the top level.

You want to use [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.top)

Comment: window.top.document.body.clientHeight gives me the same height as window.parent.document.body.clientHeight... and this height is too small

Comment: well I believe you should be using innerHeight for non IE browsers

Comment: worked perfectly for me! here is all my code: `window.parent.innerHeight` Saved me a ton of time! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Also note that window.parent is a reference to the `window` object for the hosting document. So you can do `window.parent.innerHeight` (or `window.top.innerHeight`)

Though there is no single way of obtaining the height of the document window, cross brower. See [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa/11744120#11744120) for a quick, cross browser solution and a more detailed explanation

Comment: window.top.innerHeight: I just get "undefined" with IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit and found the following one as the for me working solution:

```
top.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].offsetHeight
```